# Linker error in Meson & Ninja when trying to add custom dependency

Tags: linker, dependencies, linker-errors, meson-build

I am trying to add source-based library to my project using Meson. But when I try doing that, I get object file linking errors.

I tried adding custom dependency to project executable, but of course, it says it is undefined(`srclibdep` in code ahead), since it is defined after project executable. But if I define before Project executable, then I can't link.

This is my ./meson.build

```rb
project('ProjectName', 'cpp', version: '0.1', default_options: ['warning_level=3', 'cpp_std=c++14'])

srclibinc = include_directories('SourceLibraryName')
cpp = meson.get_compiler('cpp')
add_languages('cpp')
proj = executable('ProjectName', 'main.cpp', install: true, include_directories: srclibinc)
srclibdep = declare_dependency(include_directories: srclibinc, link_with: proj)
```

And ./SourceLibraryName/meson.build

```rb
files = run_command('files.sh').stdout().strip().split('\n')

foreach f: files
        install_headers(f)
endforeach

srclib = shared_library('SourceLibrary', files, install: true)
pkg_mod = import('pkgconfig')
pkg_mod.generate(libraries: srclib, version: '0.1', name: 'libsrc', description: 'Source-based library.')
```

I am getting hundreds of linking errors saying that `x::Y` reference doesn't exist, but compiler compiled the code as if dependency is already there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it should be

```
// make srclib available to code below:
subdir('SourceLibraryName')

// create dependency object with library to link against:
srclibdep = declare_dependency(link_with: srclib)

// add this object to dependencies:
proj = executable('ProjectName', 'main.cpp', install: true, include_directories: srclibinc, dependencies : srclibdep)
```

PS:

Not related to the matter, but just noticed:

- you don't have to generate pkg-config file if you use shared library only in your project
- it's good practice to add version to shared library, especially if it will be shared with other projects:

  shared_library('SourceLibrary', files, install: true, version : meson.project_version())

meson.project_version() you can use for pkg-config file as well, so you won't forget update it in all places

- you don't install any headers for library, so other projects won't find API that your library provides

Comment: Thanks. Do you have any idea how to fix Linker problem that `__atomic_load_4` and other atomics are unreferenced? Tried doing `add_global_arguments('-latomic', language: 'cpp')` and `cpp_args: '-latomic'` to executable, but they seem to do literally nothing.

Comment: @Mr.DeleteMyMessages try add_global_link_arguments(), language is not needed, or maybe even better add_project_link_arguments which limits the scope

Comment: Tried that too, `link_args: '-latomic'` in executable and changing `cpp_std=gnu++17`(Because I heard that atomic problem is only in Clang, not GCC), but none of them seem to work.

Comment: @Mr.DeleteMyMessages just found how mesa handles this: check https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/mesa/mesa/blob/master/meson.build search for dep_atomic object, but in your case just using dep_atomic = cc.find_library('atomic') and then add to the list of dependencies to executable(...) might be enough